# Get Maximo Work Order Information to Excel Automatically

Tags: vba, excel, maximo

I want to be able to achieve the following. I have a spreadsheet in Excel that looks as follows:

```
Work Order Nr.    Description         Etc.    Etc.    Etc.
501-51294232      Some Work Order
```

What I want to happen, is that when I enter the work order number (501-51294232) while the other fields are blank, the other fields must be filled in automatically by extracting the relevant data from Maximo.

Is there a solution available that already does this for you? I have had a look at doing this via VBA, but the only method I could find of extracting information from Maximo is downloading it to a Excel spreadsheet or CSV file.

The required solution will need to:

1. Find the relevant work order on Maxmimo.
2. Extract the necessary information.
3. Fill the fields in the active workbook with the relevant information.

I know VBA, and am willing to create a solution myself, but need some pointers to at least the channels which to use to find the relevant work orders on Maximo and extract the data to Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [MXLoader](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/community/MxLoader)

MxLoader
Extract and load data in Maximo with ease

MxLoader is a Microsoft® Excel® spreadsheet that allows to quickly and easily query and load data into IBM Maximo, IBM SmartCloud Control Desk (SCCD) and other TPAE based applications.
It brings together the power of the Maximo Integration Framework and the flexibility of Excel allowing to quickly manipulate and import data into any Maximo database.

MxLoader runs on Microsoft Excel 2007/2010/2013. It also requires Microsoft XML Core Services 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into two approaches, the first would be seeing if you can connect to the data source where that information is contained. Then it'd just be a matter of setting up the connection string, and passing in the ID to do the query.

The other approach which may work (sorry I haven't used Maximo), is to 'screen scrape'. From what I was able to see Maximo is a web based application. Honestly in this case I'd consider using Autohotkey, it makes grabbing this type of information easy. If you are planning on still using VBA, take a look [here](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/screen-scraping-101-with-vba/).

Comment: I really like the screen scraping approach, a valuable tool whether I will use it here or not! Thanks for the share!